# Dropbox API on Android - Download file to storage

Tags: android

I'm trying to download a file using the DropboxAPI v2. to internal storage  using an access token.

This is the code I'm running, everything runs but then when I check my Android phone no file is added to the internal storage.

**Code**:

```
    // Create Dropbox client
    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial", "en_US");
    DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);

    // Download the 1st file in the Apps Folder
    File path = context.getFilesDir();
    FileMetadata metadata = (FileMetadata) client.files().listFolder("").getEntries().get(0);
    File file = new File(path, metadata.getName());

    // Make sure the Downloads directory exists.
    if (!path.exists()) {
        if (!path.mkdirs()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create directory: " + path);
        }
    } else if (!path.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Download path is not a directory: " + path);
    }

    // Download the file.
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        client.files().download(metadata.getPathLower(), metadata.getRev())
                .download(outputStream);
    }

    Log.i("Check : ", "File Downloaded");

    // Tell android about the file
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission?

Comment: @ShinilMS isn't that for external storage rather than internal storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.getFilesDir()` will give you `/data/data/{your package name}/files` which is not accessible by other apps. You should use something like, `getExternalFilesDir()`

Comment: I changed the code to `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);` and added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and it worked

Comment: Happy to help you.